# Determine the basis for this subspace in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> $x=2t$, $y=-t$, $z=4t$

Ok the last one I thought was easy and I got it wrong, so I'm going to verify this one too.
Now this time, this is a line, so the dimension should be 1.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2t \\ -t \\ 4t \end{bmatrix} 
= t \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} $$

Therefore the basis vector is
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me (although I would say a basis vector, rather than the basis vector, since any nonzero scalar multiple of that vector serves equally well as a basis vector).

Comment: Oh yeah, point taken. Thanks @GerryMyerson